# How to Play streams URL without extensions video.js

Tags: javascript, html, http-live-streaming, video.js

http://exampleDomain/user/pass/56738

http://force102.com:8080/user/pass/6508

This is example stream url , my player working when Url have extension for example 
http://exampledomain.com:8080/user/pass/6508.m3u8

I`m using Video.js and video.js hls.

```
if(Hls.isSupported()) {
    var hls = new Hls();
    hls.loadSource(c);
    hls.attachMedia(myPlayer);
    hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function () {
        myPlayer.play();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the server returns a valid manifest, with the correct mime type, it will play. The player doesn’t care about, or even look at the file extension.

It the stream is not playing, there is something wrong with the stream or url, not the player.

Comment: But that it is valid stream URL, and it`s possible to play on other players